# spring security No qualifying bean of type AuthenticationSuccessHandler and AuthenticationFalureHandler

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

```
@Component("MyAuthFilter")
        public class MyAuthFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private int errCode = 0;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManager")
    //@Override
    public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler, AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler) {
        super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        this.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler);
        this.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(failureHandler);
    }

    @Override
    public AuthenticationFailureHandler getFailureHandler() {
        SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler handler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();
        handler.setDefaultFailureUrl("/login?error=" + errCode);
        return handler;
    }

    @Override
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler getSuccessHandler() {
        SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler handler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        handler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/courses");
        return handler;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        System.out.println("running my own version of UsernmePasswordFilter ... ");

        String login = (String) request.getParameter("login");
        String password = (String) request.getParameter("password");
        errCode = validate(login,password);       
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(login, password);
        // Allow subclasses to set the "details" property
        setDetails(request, authRequest);

        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
    }

    private int validate(String login,String password){

        if (login.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty()){
            return 4;
        } 
        if (login.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()){
            return 2;
        } 
            if (!login.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty()){
            return 3;
        } 

        return 1;
    }
}
```

this is MyAuthFilter.

and here my spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd">

    <http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/courses*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <custom-filter  before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="MyAuthFilter" />
        <form-login
            login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/courses"
            authentication-failure-url="/login"
            username-parameter="loginField"
            password-parameter="passwordField" />
        <csrf disabled="true" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="ars" password="1234" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

when i try to start my app i got an exceptions for

No qualifying bean of type AuthenticationSuccessHandler

and same error for FailureHandler. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Try adding `@EnableWebSecurity` to your security config. Based on context I don't think you are using Spring Boot, which would normally take care of this automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AuthenticationSuccessHandler isn't declared as a bean.
Your should create it as bean and register in your spring-security.xml in  tag via attribute
 authentication-success-handler-ref="nameOfYouSuccessHandlerBean"

So it will be look like:
some where in configuration java files:

```
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler mySuccessHandler() {
        SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler handler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        handler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/courses");
        return handler;
    }
```

and in spring-security.xml

```
 <form-login
            login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/courses"
            authentication-failure-url="/login"
            username-parameter="loginField"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="mySuccessHandler"            
            password-parameter="passwordField" />
```

Comment: how can i configure mySuccessHandler with xml instead of configuration java file?

Comment: Of course, 

<bean id="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="net.test.employee.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl">
        <property name="defaultTargedUrl" value="/courses" />
    </bean> 

in your spring.xml